# Application of the Central Limit Theorem to a Succession

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to resolve the following problem:

> $\{X_n\}$  is a succession of random variables with probability function:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> X_n & 2 - \frac{1}{n} & 3 - \frac{1}{n} & 4 - \frac{1}{n} \\ \hline
> p(x) & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> Can the central limit theorem be applied to this succession? Eplain.

My main problem is that I do not understand the central limit theory and therefore I do not know what I have to prove.

Could anyone assist me in understanding the concept or at least what calculations I need to do to prove this theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem See reference.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I don't understand the concept or how to apply it.

Comment: The basic concept is that the sum (centered at $0$) divided by $\sqrt{n}$ tends to a normal distribution.  To answer your original question, you need to assume independence and show the variances are well behaved (see article).